# Example on POST request in html having xml as request data

Tags: javascript, html, web-services, xmlhttprequest

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">

</script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

  $("button").click(function(){

    $.post("url",

    '<MESSAGE><HEADER><LOGIN>005693</LOGIN></HEADER><SESSION><LATITUDE>0.0</LATITUDE><LONGITUDE>0.0</LONGITUDE><APP>SRO</APP><ORG>MNM</ORG><TRANSACTION>PRELOGIN</TRANSACTION><KEY>PRELOGIN/ID</KEY><TYPE>PRELOGIN</TYPE></SESSION><PAYLOAD><PRELOGIN><ID>005693</ID><USERNAME>005693</USERNAME><PASSWORD>tech@2014</PASSWORD></PRELOGIN></PAYLOAD></MESSAGE>',

    function(data,status){

      alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);

    });

  });

});

</script>

</head>

<body>


<button>Send an HTTP POST request to a page and get the result back</button>


</body>

</html>
```

Have tried the same but gives origin null is not allowed by access control allow origin
HI I Have a web request to send with xml request body as post request to a url in html How can I achieve this . I got JBOSS server at another end or any other server as to say

```
<MESSAGE>
  <HEADER>
    <LOGIN>1111</LOGIN>
  </HEADER>
  <SESSION>
    <LATITUDE>0.0</LATITUDE>
    <LONGITUDE>0.0</LONGITUDE>
    <APP>SRO</APP>
    <ORG>MNM</ORG>
    <TRANSACTION>PRELOGIN</TRANSACTION>
    <KEY>PRELOGIN/ID</KEY>
    <TYPE>PRELOGIN</TYPE>
  </SESSION>
  <PAYLOAD>
    <PRELOGIN>
      <ID>1111</ID>
      <USERNAME>1111</USERNAME>
      <PASSWORD>passsss</PASSWORD>
    </PRELOGIN>
  </PAYLOAD>
</MESSAGE>
```

I have tried everything but I get a status as 0 but readystate as 1 and then 4

I tried the same thing with the below code

Answer (score 2):

The only things that differ from doing a regular POST request with XMLHttpRequest when you are sending XML are that you must:

- Use [`setRequestHeader("Content-Type: application/xml")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#setRequestHeader%28%29) to specify that you are sending XML.
- When you [`send(data)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#send%28%29) make sure that `data` consists of a string representation of your XML (i.e. don't leave it as a DOM object).

> I have tried everything but I get a status as 0 but readystate as 1 and then 4

It sounds like you are making a cross-origin request and you don't have permission. Look at your browser's error console.  It is probably complaining about that. See [this question](/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy) if that is the case.

Comment: How to make it a string respresentation ... I am directly using it under a <script> as var data = '<MESSAGE><HEADER><LOGIN>1111</LOGIN></HEADER><SESSION><LATITUDE>0.0</LATITUDE><LONGITUDE>0.0</LONGITUDE><APP>SRO</APP><ORG>MNM</ORG><TRANSACTION>PRELOGIN</TRANSACTION><KEY>PRELOGIN/ID</KEY><TYPE>PRELOGIN</TYPE></SESSION><PAYLOAD><PRELOGIN><ID>1111</ID><USERNAME>1111</USERNAME><PASSWORD>passsss</PASSWORD></PRELOGIN></PAYLOAD></MESSAGE>';

Comment: @Yatin — That's already a string representation.

Comment: am I correct?? Please lemme know

Comment: Then I am creating a 

  
req.open("POST",url,true);
console.log("6");
req.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/xml");
req.setRequestHeader("Encoding","utf-8");

req.send(data);

Comment: I get a ready state of 1 initially and then 4 ... what could be the problem\

Comment: Getting ready states 1 and 4 are normal behaviour. They don't indicate any problem.

Comment: Ok ... if its a cross origin policy how can i resolve it

Comment: See the very last sentence of the answer.

Comment: I don't get states of 2 and 3 in between ...

Comment: That just means the response loaded quickly enough that those steps were skipped. It isn't a problem.

Comment: I tried to stop it with alert having if and else clause ... they don't get inside there and lastly I have used 

if (req.readyState==4 && req.status==200)
    {
 
  console.log("ready state accepted");
  xmlDoc=req.responseXML;
  console.log("xmlDoc"+xmlDoc);
  alert("xmlDoc"+xmlDoc);
  txt="";
  x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("FIRSTNAME");
  y=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("LASTNAME");
  console.log("Response achieved"+x);
  window.open("http://www.google.com");
    }
 else
 {
  alert("Not accessed !!!");
 }

It goes to else part where the ready state of 4 is there but status  comes as 0

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47411/discussion-between-yatin-and-quentin)

Comment: TRIED IN REST CONSOLE I GET THE XML RESPONSE THERE ... SO I CAN ASSUME IT AS CROSS DOMAIN PROBLEM

Comment: Please don't post blocks of code in comments. If you want to add detail to your question, edit the question. (Also, don't post in ALL CAPS as it comes across as shouting.)

Comment: How to check brower error console